# No Grub Loader in Acer Aspire E15

Tags: grub2, 17.04

No GRUB Loader in Acer Aspire 15.. Tried hitting `Shift` And `Esc` and as well as both(`Shift+Esc`) combination. But didn't get the loader menu.

Answer (score 0):

How about hitting <kbd>F12</kbd> key. It works on my Acer Aspire E15.

Comment: <kbd>Shift</kbd> is used for legacy boot. If your system boots using UEFI, press <kbd>Esc</kbd>
 
For permanent change edit your `/etc/default/grub` file -- place a "#" symbol at the start of line `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0` or in newer version `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu` and `GRUB_TIMEOUT=<number_more_than_0_default_is_10`